# Setting up Shoulda under Test/Unit in Rails 3 (3.0.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shoulda, testunit

I have posted this in other places but no response. Trying to get Shoulda working inside Test/Unit in Rails 3.0.3 (1.9.2). When I try to run the test (copied below), I get this error:

test/unit/practice_member_test.rb:4:in `<class:PracticeMemberTest>': undefined method`context' for PracticeMemberTest:Class (NoMethodError)

Note that I have another Rails 3 project with Rspec including Shoulda also and it works fine via Rspec. In the failing project I tried placing  "require 'shoulda'" in test helper to no avail, but when I run the debugger and type Shoulda, the object is found, so the library is being loaded.

Here is my test:

require 'test_helper'

class PracticeMemberTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  context "practice member" do
    should "get global practice member count not including Demo Practice" do
      assert_equal PracticeMember.practice_members_global_count, 0

```
  practice = Factory.create(:practice_one)

  practice_member = Factory.create(:practice_member)
  practice_member.practice_id = practice.id
  practice_member.save
  practice_member = Factory.create(:practice_member)
  practice_member.practice_id = practice.id
  practice_member.save

  assert_equal PracticeMember.practice_members_global_count, 2
end
```

end
end

Must be something I am overlooking as I have not seen anyone with this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the following to your config/environment.rb file:

```
  Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    config.gem "shoulda", :lib => "shoulda"
  end
```

Then

```
 $ rake gems:install
 $ rake gems:unpack
```

As suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda)?

Comment: Sorry that was for Rails 2, in Rails 3 have you added the appropriate gems to bundler? group :test do
    gem "shoulda"
    gem "rspec-rails", "2.0.0.beta.12"
  end

Comment: Thanks... the thing is I don't want to use Rspec. That is the question... I see on the readme for Rails 3 that there are no instructions for using Shoulda with Test/Unit... did they drop support? I hope not, as well does not really make sense.